# How to solve this problem: ERROR ITMS-90725: SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK

Tags: flutter, xcode14, itms90725

I am reaching out to seek your assistance with an issue I have been encountering while attempting to upload my app to the App Store using fastlane in flutter 2.10 and xcode 14.2. Unfortunately, the submission has been repeatedly failing, and I have received the following error message: “ERROR ITMS-90725: SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.”

I am perplexed because I have already upgraded to xcode 14.2, so I am unsure why I am still encountering this issue. Would anyone be able to provide any guidance or assistance on how to resolve this problem?

Is it possible to solve this problem without upgrading the flutter version?